# Is it possible to get the company's link, Using Company Name in RapidMiner?

Tags: rapidminer

have list of company names in an excel file. is it possible to get the respective company links in Rapidminer? If yes, kindly let me know how.

Example:

Company Name: Accurate Automation Corporation (input)

using the company name mentioned above, i need to extract its company link which i have shown below in rapidminer.

Company Link http://www.accurate-automation.com (output)

Thank You in Advance

Vijay

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a Whois lookup service by issuing a suitable HTTP GET containing the company name within the URL parameters (you would have to reverse engineer an interactive session with a Whois service first). From there, you could parse the returned content to determine the best match for the input company.